# Package jack is not available on Ubuntu 20.04, is it not required?

Tags: 20.04, jack

I did a package search for [jack](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jack).

and find that it is not available on Ubuntu 20.04.

Is it not required on Ubuntu 20.04 to connect audio devices?
If required how can I backport?

Comment: Sorry the heading should end with "is it not required?"

Comment: Can't you edit your own questions, you should be able to.

Comment: That package relied on python(2) which has been removed due to python 2.x being EOL.  It needed to be ported to python3 for it to remain (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/jack)

Comment: Just because I am curious: I remember that that Jack used to be bundled with Ubuntu Studio and I checked with `apt-cache policy *jack*` when running Ubuntu Studio persistent live: it *is* ported to Ubuntu Studio 20.04. You can use that or install it the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can still install it using packages from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-pathlib/python-pathlib_1.0.1-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eyed3/python-eyed3_0.8.4-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-cddb/python-cddb_1.4-5.3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jack/jack_3.1.1+cvs20050801-29.2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-eyed3_0.8.4-2_all.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./jack_3.1.1+cvs20050801-29.2_amd64.deb ./python-cddb_1.4-5.3_amd64.deb ./python-pathlib_1.0.1-2_all.deb
```